# CSS grid layout where child React components contain multiple cells for the grid

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I'm making a three-column layout in React for a shopping list app. The columns are "item search", "shopping list", and "item details". Each column has a header div containing controls specific to that column, and a contents div beneath:

[image]

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/commscheck/pen/zYyqRmP

My original plan was to have a component for each column, to nicely encapsulate the logic of each. Then the top-level app would look something like:

```html
<RootLayout>
  <ItemSearchColumn onItemAdded={...} />
  <ShoppingListColumn items={...} onItemRemoved={...} onItemSelected={...} />
  <ItemDetailsColumn selectedItem={...} />
</RootLayout>
```

However, I want the top edge of the three bottom divs to line up.

I could use CSS grid to achieve this layout like I've done in the codepen above, but the `RootLayout` component has no visibility of each column component's children.

Is there a way I can achieve this layout, without needing to shift each column's business logic up into the parent "layout" component?

Comment: They already do, don't they?. Also I would recommend some padding.

Comment: I guess you could use `subgrid` - its not everywhere yet but thats what you are looking for I think.